# How to redirect to mypage.com#?test=1 using html forms + javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, get

I have page which handle dynamically some data. I want to redirect to that page from some static pages using form with value of `test` field - I need to send parameters with `#`. How can I do it?

```
<form class="search-form" method="get" action="#?">
        <input type="text" name="test" />
</form>
```

This solution ofc doesn't work.

I want for example write "1" in my form and then I should be redirected to `mypage.com#?test=1`.

Is there any function which parse form to generate url so I could just redirect? Or to just get value from submitting button link without actually redirecting?

Comment: You will have to use javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('button#testclick').click(function() {
        var serialized = $('form#searchByTitle').serialize();
        var url = "/search";
        location.replace(url + "#?" + serialized);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Thats my solution. It works with AngularJS routing :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="search-form" method="get" action="">
            <input type="text" id="testbox" name="test" />
            <input type="button" id="button" onclick="hello()" value="send">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function hello(){
                var current_url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + "#";
                location.replace(current_url + "?test=" + document.getElementById('testbox').value);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Its not wrong, but its not universal :) I need more universal solution.